# How to control task deduplication feature in Google Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm looking at the documentation here: 
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview 
And in quotas here: 
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas 
I still not sure how I can enable or disable this deduplication feature.
I wonder if I can set `Task de-duplication window`

Answer (score 8):

Task deduplication refers to making sure you don't have *duplicate names of tasks*.

Per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create#body.request_body.FIELDS.task) it works like this:

> Explicitly specifying a task ID enables task de-duplication. If a task's ID is identical to that of an existing task or a task that was deleted or executed recently then the call will fail with `google.rpc.Code.ALREADY_EXISTS`. If the task's queue was created using Cloud Tasks, then another task with the same name *can't be created for ~1hour after the original task was deleted or executed.*
> If the task's queue was created using queue.yaml or queue.xml, then another task with the same name can't be created for ~9days after the original task was deleted or executed.

> Because there is an extra lookup cost to identify duplicate task names, these [`tasks.create`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create#google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.CloudTasks.CreateTask) calls have **significantly increased latency**.

Comment: It mentions task "ID". There is no property "ID" in Task, as seen here https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task
Is it "name"?

Comment: @WerBn Yes, apparently it is task.name and is is composed of `${parent}/tasks/YOUR_TASK_ID` where `parent` is the value you got from `client.queuePath(...)`

Answer (score 6):

We had the same problem.

To not spam users, we've been looking for a mechanism that we could use to control the de-duplication feature for certain notification types.

Since they check TASK_ID - we can use it to control de-duplication by adding something unique. For example a timestamp.

> TASK_ID is the last part of the [task name](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task.FIELDS.name). Task name looks like this -
> `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/queues/QUEUE_ID/tasks/TASK_ID`.

If we need to create a task that will be executed once per 10 seconds - we can generate a name like this - `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/queues/QUEUE_ID/tasks/notification-like-${timestamp}`.

Other tasks created within these 10 seconds will be rejected with an error.

**JavaScript snippet that generates a task name**

```js
/**
 * Round time up to given coefficient.
 * @param {number} coefficient - Coefficient in milliseconds.
 */
const roundTime = (coefficient) => {
    const date = new Date();
    return new Date(Math.ceil(date.getTime() / coefficient) * coefficient).getTime();
};

const coefficient = 1000 * 10; // Trigger once per 10 seconds
const taskId = `notification-like-${roundTime(coefficient)}`;
const taskName = `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/queues/QUEUE_ID/tasks/${taskId}`;

console.log(taskName);
// projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/queues/QUEUE_ID/tasks/notification-like-1643898560000
```

Comment: See the response from @Andres S. We can't manage deduplication/debounce with the task id, I just encountered the problem ...

Comment: I would say managing is not recommended. The described solution will spam GCP with deduplication errors. It's a kind of hack that worked for us. We didn't have enough time and resources to fix it on our application side. If you can control deduplication on your app side, please do! That would be a better approach!